# How to interface this DFS code with a Boost Graph DFS?

Tags: c++, depth-first-search, callable, boost-graph

### Background

I have defined formatting operations on trees that work pretty well when they are used a pre/in/post order operators with the following structure and DFS definition (it works also on k-ary trees):

```cpp
struct Node
{
  Node *parent = nullptr;
  Node *left = nullptr;
  Node *right = nullptr;
  char data;

  template<class Op1, class Op2, class Op3>
  void depth_first_search(Op1 pre_order, Op2 in_order, Op3 post_order)
  {
    pre_order(*this);
    if(this->left != nullptr && this->right != nullptr)
    {
      this->left->depth_first_search(pre_order, in_order, post_order);
      in_order(*this);
      this->right->depth_first_search(pre_order, in_order, post_order);
      in_order(*this);
    }
    post_order(*this);
  }
};
```

I can format this structure with the following:

```cpp
Formatter formatter(my_config);
tree.depth_first_search(formatter.get_pre_order(), formatter.get_in_order(), formatter.get_post_order());
auto result = formatter.take_result();
```

### Objective

Since they work nicely, I would like to re-use the same functors to operate formatting on Boost graphs when they have values of trees. So I am trying to get this (approximate/buggy) syntax working:

```cpp
    template<class Formatter>
    class my_visitor : boost::default_dfs_visitor
    {
      Formatter & _formatter;

      public:
      my_visitor(Formatter& formatter) : _formatter(formatter){}

      auto discover_vertex(auto vertex, auto const& g)
      { 
        auto f =  _formatter.get_pre_order();
        f(vertex);
      }

      auto examine_edge(auto edge, auto const& g)
      {
        auto f =  _formatter.get_in_order();
        f(edge);
      }

      auto finish_vertex(auto vertex, auto const& g)
      { 
        auto f =  _formatter.get_post_order();
        f(vertex);
      }
    };
```

So I can format the tree using a syntax like

```cpp
Formatter formatter(my_config);
my_visitor vis(formatter);
depth_first_search(graph, root, boost::visitor(vis));
auto s = formatter.take_result();
```

### Code

In its present state, the code compiles and run on Gobolt: https://godbolt.org/z/bzjqjbvE3

However, the last method called in the main function does not exist (yet) since I don't know how to specify it:

```cpp
auto s = newick::generate_from(tree);
```

There is a commented draft of such function but I struggle fitting it to BGL:

```cpp
  ///
  /// @brief Generate a Newick string from a k-ary tree with no properties attached to edges or vertices
  ///
  std::string generate_from(quetzal::coalescence::k_ary_tree<> graph)
  {
    using vertex_t = typename quetzal::coalescence::k_ary_tree<>::vertex_descriptor;

    // Data access
    std::predicate<vertex_t>      auto has_parent    = [&graph](vertex_t v){ return graph.has_parent(v); };
    std::predicate<vertex_t>      auto has_children  = [&graph](vertex_t v){ return graph.has_children(v); };
    newick::Formattable<vertex_t> auto label         = [&graph](auto){ return ""; };
    newick::Formattable<vertex_t> auto branch_length = [&graph](auto){ return ""; };

    // We declare a generator passing it the data interfaces
    auto generator = newick::make_generator(has_parent, has_children, label, branch_length);

    // We expose its interface to the boost DFS algorithm
    detail::newick_no_property_visitor vis(generator);

    depth_first_search(graph, boost::visitor(vis));
  }
```

### Problem

I can not really wrap my head around the interface consistency and I struggle identifying the root (lol) of the problem:

- the pre/in/post operations as I defined them are callables with 1 parameter having a `Node` semantic (encapsulating both the node identifier and the graph it refers to)
- whereas visitors methods defined by the BGL have heterogenous signatures taking either vertex + graph or edge + graph parameters.
- I also struggle mapping the pre/in/post order operations to the BGL visitor more convoluted interface. I think that `pre-order` maps to `discover_vertex`, `in_order` maps to `examine_edge` and `post_order` maps to `finish_vertex`, although I am not certain ?

Is there a way to reconcile these two interfaces or their semantic is too different and I have to duplicate/modify the formatting grammar?

Comment: That DFS looks questionable to me. Why is in_order called with the same node twice, and why is no branch visited unless both are non-null?

Comment: huhoooo ... The in_order is called with the same node twice because it is meant to add a separator character between the children node if those exist (aka pointers are not null). In my domain problem for binary trees you can't have a node with only one child, nodes are either leaves or bifurcating internals. If it makes sense?

Comment: I guess. How do you represent those invariants in boost? I guess you don't? That feels like a leaky abstraction waiting to cause problems.

Comment: I would love to help, but I cannot wrap my head around how this would actually work out for your Formatter. This is where I got stuck: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8074d4dc9dd9d7f2 - Thinking about your "delimiter" explanation, I'm starting to think that the solution to the riddle must be that you're apparently printing the data from `pre` or `post`. Which somewhat begs the question (from the opposite side) why `*this` is passed to `in_order` at all, since ... it's not useful there?

Comment: Anyways. I was posting that to ask **you** to make your question code self-contained example demonstrating the goal, so I can spend my time on answering the BGL question instead.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the leaky abstraction. For the moment I don't really represent these invariants - mostly because I need to learn more about BGL before I am able to make an interface around BGL that does not break these invariants. Note that Jeremy Murphy pointed me to a boost branch with a cardinal k ary tree class https://github.com/jeremy-murphy/graph/blob/k-ary-tree/include/boost/graph/k-ary_tree.hpp - I copied the code because it would be nice for binary trees, but I also would need a non-cardinal k-ary tree, and users of my code would have their own leaky binary tree class

Comment: Ok I will update the code sehe!

Comment: Okay, first note: since your branch_length lambda returns `char const[]`, the comparison `if (branch != "")` is actually unspecified behaviour. I'd use a string_view e.g. to disambiguate (`if (!std::string_view(branch).empty())`)

Comment: wooh thank you I would not have spotted this one!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251161/discussion-between-sehe-and-waterfox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on it. Instead of generating a random graph, let's replicate the exact graph that you treated with your "old-style `Node*` 2-ary tree":

```
using G = quetzal::coalescence::k_ary_tree<>;
using V = G::vertex_descriptor;

enum {a,b,c,d,e,N};
G tree(N);
/*
 *       a
 *      /  \
 *     /    c
 *    /    / \
 *   b    d   e
 */
add_edge(a, b, tree);
add_edge(a, c, tree);
add_edge(c, d, tree);
add_edge(c, e, tree);

auto name_map = boost::make_function_property_map<V>([](V v) -> char { return 'a' + v; });

print_graph(tree, name_map);
```

Prints

```
a --> b c 
b -->
c --> d e
d -->
e -->
```

### Implementing The DFS Visitor

The key is to wrap the "formatter" (`generator`) into a DFS visitor suitably.

Some notes:

- the events exposed don't map 1:1
- visitors are copied, so to refer to the same generator, the visitor should hold a *reference* to it
- to make this easily extensible, I put the generator inside a `State` struct:

```
// We declare a generator passing it the data interfaces
struct State {
    newick::generator<V, P, P, F, F, decltype(flavor)> gen;
    std::stack<int> nth_child;
} state{{has_parent, has_children, label, branch_length, flavor}, {}};

// We expose its interface to the boost DFS algorithm
struct VisWrap : boost::default_dfs_visitor {
    State& state_;
    VisWrap(State& ref) : state_(ref) {}
    void discover_vertex(V v, G const&) const {
        state_.nth_child.push(0);
        state_.gen.pre_order()(v);
    }
    void finish_vertex(V v, G const&) const {
        state_.gen.post_order()(v);
        state_.nth_child.pop();
    }
    void tree_edge(E e, G const& g) const {
        if (state_.nth_child.top()++ > 0)
            state_.gen.in_order()(target(e, g));
    }
} vis{state};

depth_first_search(graph, boost::visitor(vis));
return state.gen.take_result();
```

### Side Notes/Bug

1. You had mixed up `in_edges` and `out_edges` inside `has_parent()` and `has_children()`. So I changed those from:

   ```
    bool has_parent(vertex_descriptor v) const {
        auto [it1, it2] = out_edges(v, *this);
        // since it is a tree, at most 1 parent
        assert(std::distance(it1,it2) <= 1);
        // if iterators equal, then no parent
        return it1 == it2 ? false : true;
    }

    bool has_children(vertex_descriptor v) const {
        auto [it1, it2] = in_edges(v, *this);
        return std::distance(it1, it2) >= 1;
    }
   ```

   Into the (slightly modernized):

   ```
   bool has_parent(vertex_descriptor v) const {
       auto pp = make_iterator_range(in_edges(v, *this));
       // since it is a tree, at most 1 parent
       assert(boost::size(pp) <= 1);
       return !pp.empty();
   }

   bool has_children(vertex_descriptor v) const {
       return !make_iterator_range(out_edges(v, *this)).empty();
   }
   ```
2. Note that using `in_edges` **does** necessitate changing to a model of BidirectionalGraph by changing

   ```
   using directed_type = boost::directedS;
   ```

   into

   ```
   using directed_type = boost::bidirectionalS; // for boost::in_edges
   ```
3. Due to the [timing issues of the generator operations vs. the visitor events](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55835237#55835237) I had to add some guards around adding/removing the comma delimiters. I have a feeling that if you remove the "impedance mismatch" in this area things will become simpler.
4. There's some work left that you left out of scope for this question (good idea), meaning actually generalizing for the label/length functions.

### Full Demo

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/3MvMWGshK)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/isomorphism.hpp>
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

namespace quetzal::coalescence {
    namespace details {
        ///
        /// @brief Defines the desired properties and constraints for a coalescent graph
        ///
        struct tree_traits {
            /// @brief Trees are sparse graph in nature, adjacency_matrix would not be justified here
            template <class... Types> using model = boost::adjacency_list<Types...>;
            /// @brief We want to enforce avoiding multi-graphs (edges with same end nodes)
            using out_edge_list_type = boost::setS;
            /// @brief We don't allow for inserting vertices except at the end and we don't remove vertices.
            ///        This means that neither reallocation cost nor stability are reasons for preferring
            ///        listS to vecS.
            using vertex_list_type = boost::vecS;
            /// @brief Coalescent trees are directed acyclic graphs
            using directed_type = boost::bidirectionalS; // for boost::in_edges
        };
    } // namespace details

    ///
    /// @brief A class adapted for simulating coalescent trees as a rooted K-ary tree, where each node can
    /// hold at most k number of children.
    ///
    /// @remark
    ///   - Since topology (pure structure) matter, a coalescence tree is more than a data container.
    ///   - This class inherits from as a boost::graph with specialized edge and vertex properties
    ///   defined in details#tree_traits
    ///   - The simulation interface intentionally does not allow for removing edges or vertices,
    ///  but you may access the underlying boost graph object to do so.
    ///
    template <class VertexProperties = boost::no_property, class EdgeProperties = boost::no_property>
    struct k_ary_tree
        : public details::tree_traits::model<
            details::tree_traits::out_edge_list_type, details::tree_traits::vertex_list_type,
            details::tree_traits::directed_type, VertexProperties, EdgeProperties> {
        /// @brief Properties of an edge, e.g. a structure representing the series of demes visited or simply
        /// the branch length.
        using edge_properties = EdgeProperties;
        /// @brief Properties of a vertex, e.g. a structure representing the mutational state.
        using vertex_properties = VertexProperties;
        /// @brief The type of graph hold by the tree class
        using base_type = details::tree_traits::model<
            details::tree_traits::out_edge_list_type, details::tree_traits::vertex_list_type,
            details::tree_traits::directed_type, vertex_properties, edge_properties>;

        using self_type = k_ary_tree<vertex_properties, edge_properties>;

        /// @brief The type used for identifying vertices within the graph
        using vertex_descriptor = typename self_type::vertex_descriptor;

        /// @brief Inherit all constructor from boost graph
        using base_type::base_type;

        ///
        /// @brief Print the tree to the graphviz format
        /// @remarks Intends to hide the bundles writer syntax
        ///
        void to_graphviz(std::ostream& out) const {
            using namespace boost;
            return boost::write_graphviz(out, *this,
                                        boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(vertex_bundle, *this)),
                                        boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(edge_bundle, *this)));
        }

        ///
        /// @brief Returns true if there exists an isomorphism between this and other and false otherwise.
        ///
        template <class T> bool is_isomorphic(T const& other) noexcept {
            return boost::isomorphism(*this, other);
        }

        ///
        /// @brief Returns true if a given node has a parent node
        ///
        bool has_parent(vertex_descriptor v) const {
            auto pp = make_iterator_range(in_edges(v, *this));
            // since it is a tree, at most 1 parent
            assert(boost::size(pp) <= 1);
            return !pp.empty();
        }

        ///
        /// @brief Returns true if a given node has children nodes
        ///
        bool has_children(vertex_descriptor v) const {
            return !make_iterator_range(out_edges(v, *this)).empty();
        }

    }; // end class Tree
} // end namespace quetzal::coalescence

namespace quetzal::format::newick {

    namespace detail {
        // Replacement for `std::function<T(U)>::argument_type`
        template <typename T> struct single_function_argument;

        template <typename Ret, typename Arg> struct single_function_argument<std::function<Ret(Arg)>> {
            using type = Arg;
        };

        template <typename P1> struct single_function_argument_impl {
            using type = typename single_function_argument<decltype(std::function{std::declval<P1>()})>::type;
        };

        template <typename P1>
        using single_function_argument_t = typename single_function_argument_impl<P1>::type;

        /// @brief Tag
        struct parenthesis {};

        /// @brief Tag
        struct square_bracket {};

        ///
        /// @brief Check if the string is balanced for open/close symbols (parenthesis,brackets)
        ///
        ///
        /// @note Since parenthesis checking is a context-free grammar, it requires a stack.
        ///       Regex can not accomplish that since they do not have memory.
        ///
        bool check_if_balanced(std::string_view input, char const& open = '(', char const& close = ')') {
            int count = 0;
            for (auto const& ch : input) {
                if (ch == open)
                    count++;
                if (ch == close)
                    count--;
                // if a parenthesis is closed without being opened return false
                if (count < 0)
                    return false;
            }
            // in the end the test is passed only if count is zero
            return count == 0;
        }

        ///
        /// @brief Default comment removal policy: do not change anything
        ///
        struct identity {
            static std::string edit(const std::string s) { return s; }
        };

        ///
        /// @brief Class template, base for further specialization
        ///
        template <class tag> struct is_balanced {};

        ///
        /// @brief Specialization for parenthesis
        ///
        template <> struct is_balanced<detail::parenthesis> {
            static bool check(std::string_view s) { return check_if_balanced(s, '(', ')'); }
        };

        ///
        /// @brief Specialization for square bracket
        ///
        template <> struct is_balanced<detail::square_bracket> {
            static bool check(std::string_view s) { return check_if_balanced(s, '[', ']'); }
        };
    } // namespace detail

    using namespace std::string_literals;

    ///
    /// @brief Node names can be any character except blanks, colons, semicolons, parentheses, and square
    /// brackets.
    ///
    static inline std::vector<std::string> forbidden_labels = {" "s, ","s, ";"s, "("s, ")"s, "["s, "]"s};

    ///
    /// @brief Underscore characters in unquoted labels are converted to blanks.
    ///
    /// @detail Because you may want to include a blank in a name, it is assumed
    ///         that an underscore character ("_") stands for a blank; any of
    ///         these in a name will be converted to a blank when it is read in.
    ///
    static inline constexpr char blank = '_';

    ///
    /// @brief Template class.
    ///
    template <unsigned int N> struct remove_comments_of_depth {};

    ///
    /// @brief Do not remove anything
    ///
    template <> struct remove_comments_of_depth<0> : detail::identity {};

    ///
    /// @brief Remove all comments substrings contained between square brackets
    ///
    /// @note Assumes that text is well formatted so there are no such things like [[]] or unclosed bracket
    ///
    template <> struct remove_comments_of_depth<1> {
        static std::string edit(const std::string s) {
            if (s.empty())
                return s;
            return std::regex_replace(s, std::regex(R"(\[[^()]*\])"), "");
        }
    };

    ///
    /// @brief Remove all comments substrings contained between square brackets of depth 2
    ///
    /// @note Assumes that text is well formatted so there are no such things like [[]] or unclosed bracket
    ///
    template <> struct remove_comments_of_depth<2> {
        static std::string edit(const std::string s) {
            std::string buffer;
            int         counter = 0;
            for (auto const& ch : s) {
                if (ch == '[')
                    counter++;
                if (ch == ']')
                    counter--;
                if (ch == '[' && counter == 2)
                    continue; // do nothing, that was the opening
                if (ch == ']' && counter == 1)
                    continue; // do nothing, that was the closing
                if (!(counter >= 2 || (counter == 1 && ch == ']')))
                    buffer.append(std::string(1, ch));
            }
            return buffer;
        }
    };

    ///
    /// @brief Policy allowing to keep nested comments.
    ///
    /// @note Use this as a template parameter to specialize a Newick generator policy
    ///
    struct PAUP {
        // return empty string
        static inline std::string root_branch_length() { return ""; }
        // do nothing
        static inline std::string treat_comments(std::string& s) { return s; }
    };

    ///
    /// @brief Set a root node branch length to zero, allow comments of depth 1, but will remove nested
    /// comments.
    ///
    /// @note Use this as a template parameter to specialize a Newick generator policy
    ///
    struct TreeAlign {
        // Set explicit null branch length for root node
        static inline std::string root_branch_length() { return ":0.0"; }
        // Remove comments that are nested, keep comments of depth 1
        static inline std::string treat_comments(const std::string s) {
            return remove_comments_of_depth<2>::edit(s);
        }
    };

    ///
    /// @brief Requires that an unrooted tree begin with a trifurcation; it will not "uproot" a rooted tree.
    ///        Allow comments of depth 1, but does not allow nested comments.
    /// @note Use this as a template parameter to specialize a Newick generator policy
    ///
    struct PHYLIP {
        // Branch length for root node is not explicit.
        static inline std::string root_branch_length() { return ""; }
        // Remove comments that are nested, keep comments of depth 1
        static inline std::string treat_comments(std::string& s) {
            // Allow comments of depth 1, but does not allow nested comments.
            return remove_comments_of_depth<2>::edit(s);
        }
    };

    ///
    /// @brief Concept for label name: invocable and the return type is convertible to a string.
    ///
    template <class F, class... Args>
    concept Formattable =
        std::invocable<F, Args...> && std::convertible_to<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>, std::string>;

    ///
    /// @brief Generate the Newick formula from an external (custom) tree class.
    ///
    /// @remark This is a non-intrusive interface implementation so users can reuse Newick formatting
    ///         logic and expose the formatting internals to their own Tree class's DFS.
    template <class T, std::predicate<T> P1, std::predicate<T> P2, Formattable<T> F1, Formattable<T> F2,
            class Policy = PAUP>
    class generator : public Policy {
    public:
        ///
        /// @brief Type of node being formatted
        ///
        using node_type = T;
        ///
        /// @brief Type of formula being generated
        ///
        using formula_type = std::string;
        ///
        /// @brief Type of formula being generated
        ///
        using policy_type = Policy;

    private:
        ///
        /// @brief End character.
        ///
        static inline constexpr char _end = ';';
        ///
        /// @brief The string formula to be updated.
        ///
        mutable formula_type _formula;
        ///
        /// @brief Functor inspecting if the node being visited has a parent.
        ///
        P1 _has_parent;

        ///
        /// @brief Functor inspecting if the node being visited has children.
        ///
        P2 _has_children;

        ///
        /// @brief Retrieve the name of the node being visited.
        ///
        /// @detail A name can be any string of printable characters except blanks,
        ///         colons, semicolons, parentheses, and square brackets.
        ///
        /// @remark Return type must be convertible to std::string
        ///
        F1 _label;

        ///
        /// @brief Retrieve the branch length immediately above the node being visited.
        ///
        /// @details Branch lengths can be incorporated into a tree by putting a
        ///          real number, with or without decimal point, after a node and
        ///          preceded by a colon. This represents the length of the branch
        ///          immediately above that node (that is, distance to parent node)
        /// @remark Return type must be convertible to std::string
        ///
        F2 _branch_length;

        void _pre_order(node_type const& node) const {
            if (std::invoke(_has_children, node)) {
                _formula += '(';
            }
        }

        void _in_order(node_type const&) const { _formula += ","; }

        void _post_order(node_type const& node) const {
            if (std::invoke(_has_children, node)) {
                if (_formula.back() == ',')
                    _formula.pop_back(); // Remove comma
                _formula += ')';
            }

            if (std::invoke(_has_parent, node)) {
                auto label = std::invoke(_label, node);
                if (has_forbidden_characters(remove_comments_of_depth<1>::edit(label))) {
                    throw std::invalid_argument(std::string("Label with forbidden characters:") +
                                                std::string(label));
                }

                _formula += label;

                std::string branch(std::invoke(_branch_length, node));
                if (!branch.empty()) {
                    _formula += ":";
                    _formula += branch;
                }
            } else {
                _formula += std::invoke(_label, node);
                _formula += policy_type::root_branch_length();
            }
        }

    public:
        ///
        /// @brief Constructor
        ///
        generator(P1 has_parent, P2 has_children, F1 label, F2 branch_length, Policy pol = {})
            : policy_type(std::move(pol))
            , _has_parent(std::move(has_parent))
            , _has_children(std::move(has_children))
            , _label(std::move(label))
            , _branch_length(std::move(branch_length)) {}

        ///
        /// @brief Operation called in the general DFS algorithm to open a parenthesis if node has children to
        /// be visited.
        ///
        /// @param node the node currently visited
        ///
        auto pre_order() {
            return [this](node_type const& node) { this->_pre_order(node); };
        }

        ///
        /// @brief Operation called in the general DFS algorithm to add a comma between visited nodes.
        ///
        auto in_order() {
            return [this](node_type const& node) { this->_in_order(node); };
        }

        ///
        /// @brief Operation to be passed to a generic DFS algorithm to open a parenthesis if node has
        /// children to be visited.
        ///
        /// @param node the node currently visited
        ///
        auto post_order() {
            return [this](node_type const& node) { this->_post_order(node); };
        }

        ///
        /// @brief Check if a string contains characters forbidden by the standard
        ///
        bool has_forbidden_characters(std::string const& s) const {
            if (s.empty())
                return false;
            std::string forbidden    = " ,;()[\\]";
            bool        is_forbidden = std::regex_search(s, std::regex("[" + forbidden + "]"));
            return is_forbidden;
        }

        ///
        /// @brief Clear the formula buffer to refresh the generator.
        ///
        void clear() { _formula.clear(); }

        ///
        /// @brief Retrieve the formatted string of the given node in the specified format
        ///
        std::string&& take_result() const {
            _formula.push_back(this->_end);

            _formula = policy_type::treat_comments(_formula);

            if (detail::is_balanced<detail::parenthesis>::check(_formula) == false) {
                throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed: formula parenthesis are not balanced:") +
                                        _formula);
            }

            if (detail::is_balanced<detail::square_bracket>::check(_formula) == false) {
                throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed: formula square brackets are not balanced:") +
                                        _formula);
            }

            return std::move(_formula);
        }
    }; // end structure generator

    ///
    /// @brief User-defined deduction guide where the node/graph type T is deduced from P1
    /// @remark Template deduction guides are patterns associated with a template
    ///         class that tell the compiler how to translate a set of constructor
    ///          arguments (and their types) into template parameters for the class.
    template <class P1, class P2, class F1, class F2, class Policy = PAUP>
    generator(P1, P2, F1, F2, Policy pol = {})
        -> generator<detail::single_function_argument_t<P1>, P1, P2, F1, F2, Policy>;

} // end namespace quetzal::format::newick

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/function_property_map.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

// Simplistic tree for testing - emulates implementations found in my field
struct Node {
    Node* parent = nullptr;
    Node* left   = nullptr;
    Node* right  = nullptr;
    char  data;

    template <class Op1, class Op2, class Op3>
    void depth_first_search(Op1 pre_order, Op2 in_order, Op3 post_order) {
        pre_order(*this);
        if (this->left != nullptr && this->right != nullptr) {
            this->left->depth_first_search(pre_order, in_order, post_order);
            in_order(*this);
            this->right->depth_first_search(pre_order, in_order, post_order);
            in_order(*this);
        }
        post_order(*this);
    }
};

using Flavor = quetzal::format::newick::TreeAlign;

std::string legacy_implementation() {
    /* Topology :
    *
    *       a
    *      /  \
    *     /    c
    *    /    / \
    *   b    d   e
    */
    Node a, b, c, d, e;
    a.data = 'a';
    b.data = 'b';
    c.data = 'c';
    d.data = 'd';
    e.data = 'e';

    a.left   = &b;
    b.parent = &a;
    a.right  = &c;
    c.parent = &a;
    c.left   = &d;
    d.parent = &c;
    c.right  = &e;
    e.parent = &c;

    namespace newick = quetzal::format::newick;

    // Interfacing Quetzal generator with non-quetzal tree types
    std::predicate<Node> auto has_parent   = [](Node const& n) { return n.parent; };
    std::predicate<Node> auto has_children = [](Node const& n) { return n.left && n.right; };

    // Random data is generated for the branch length
    newick::Formattable<Node> auto branch_length = [](Node const&) /*-> std::string*/ { return "0.1"; };

    // More sophisticated label formatting
    newick::Formattable<Node> auto label = [](Node const& n) {
        return std::string(1, n.data) + "[my[comment]]";
    };

    // Writes a root node branch length with a value of 0.0 and disable/remove nested comments
    newick::generator generator(has_parent, has_children, label, branch_length, Flavor());
    a.depth_first_search(generator.pre_order(), generator.in_order(), generator.post_order());

    // We retrieve the formatted string
    return generator.take_result();
}

//
// @brief Generate a Newick string from a k-ary tree with no properties attached to edges or vertices
//
std::string generate_from(quetzal::coalescence::k_ary_tree<> const& graph, auto flavor) {
    using G = quetzal::coalescence::k_ary_tree<>;
    using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
    using E = G::edge_descriptor;
    namespace newick = quetzal::format::newick;

    // Data access
    using P = std::function<bool(V)>;
    using F = std::function<std::string(V)>;

    P has_parent    = [&graph](V v) { return graph.has_parent(v); };
    P has_children  = [&graph](V v) { return graph.has_children(v); };
    F branch_length = [](V) { return "0.1"; };
    F label         = [](V v) {
        std::string r = "a[my[comment]]";
        r.front() += v;
        return r;
    };

    // We declare a generator passing it the data interfaces
    struct State {
        newick::generator<V, P, P, F, F, decltype(flavor)> gen;
        std::stack<int> nth_child;
    } state{{has_parent, has_children, label, branch_length, flavor}, {}};

    // We expose its interface to the boost DFS algorithm
    struct VisWrap : boost::default_dfs_visitor {
        State& state_;
        VisWrap(State& ref) : state_(ref) {}
        void discover_vertex(V v, G const&) const {
            state_.nth_child.push(0);
            state_.gen.pre_order()(v);
        }
        void finish_vertex(V v, G const&) const {
            state_.gen.post_order()(v);
            state_.nth_child.pop();
        }
        void tree_edge(E e, G const& g) const {
            if (state_.nth_child.top()++ > 0)
                state_.gen.in_order()(target(e, g));
        }
    } vis{state};

    depth_first_search(graph, boost::visitor(vis));
    return state.gen.take_result();
}

int main() {
    std::string const legacy = legacy_implementation();
    assert(legacy == "(b[my]:0.1,(d[my]:0.1,e[my]:0.1)c[my]:0.1)a[my]:0.0;");

    // NOW WITH BGL GRAPHS
    using G = quetzal::coalescence::k_ary_tree<>;

    enum {a,b,c,d,e,N};
    G tree(N);
    add_edge(a, b, tree);
    add_edge(a, c, tree);
    add_edge(c, d, tree);
    add_edge(c, e, tree);

    // Generate the newick string
    auto const bgl = generate_from(tree, Flavor());

    std::cout << quoted(bgl) << "\n";
    std::cout << quoted(legacy) << "\n";
    std::cout << (bgl == legacy?"matching":"MISMATCH") << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
"(b[my]:0.1,(d[my]:0.1,e[my]:0.1)c[my]:0.1)a[my]:0.0;"
"(b[my]:0.1,(d[my]:0.1,e[my]:0.1)c[my]:0.1)a[my]:0.0;"
matching
```

Comment: I am speechless ... I said it so many times but thank you!
Oopsie I guess I would have noticed mixing up the in/out-edges but I would not have thought to use Bidirectional to gain access to `in_edges`: a tree can be unidirectional and I would expect to be able to still access the incoming edges to have access to its children? It's interesting because Bidirectional refers to actually the implementation detail of a node being aware of its children, and not if the graph is itself bidirectional are not. Do I make sense?

Comment: That's 100% correct. Bidirectionality trades off storage/insertion overhead  for the ability to  get in-edges and in-degree without having to enumerate all vertices or edges.

Comment: Here's a slight adaptation that restores the predicate/Formattable concepts and gets rid of the type erasure. It now takes direct references instead of wrapping inside `State` struct: https://godbolt.org/z/M1T7jn55a (Also changed `target(e,g)` into `source(e,g)` to stay closer to the legacy implementation, even though the `in_order(Node)` argument isn't actually used in practice.

Comment: Also you first mention " into a dijkstra visitor suitably." but then you inherit from `default_dfs_visitor` and not from `djikstra_visitor` ?

Comment: That was a thinko. I'm answering more dijkstra questions lately than DFS :_ Sorry for the mixup

Comment: It just occurred to me that these are better: `bool has_parent(vertex_descriptor v) const { return in_degree(v, *this); }
bool has_children(vertex_descriptor v) const { return out_degree(v, *this); }` :)

Comment: Wonderful I was just updating them! :) There is an implicit cast from int to bool happening, right?

Comment: Note that adding the guards around the comma delimiter as stated in point 3. seems to break the formatting when labels and branch length formatting functors return empty strings ( in that case, leaves `(,)` become a simple `()`. I will work on removing the "impedance mismatch" so I can see things clearer :)

Comment: Oh, aha. I never thought that `(,)` would be valid newick. But you can figure that out, no doubt :)

Comment: Newick begins to feel like a very strange format! Yup On my way! to figure this out!